# AVD Android 4: support to OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, android-virtual-device

Does anybody know for sure if the device emulator AVD on Android 4 supports OpenGL ES 2.0? Do I need to buy a real Android device or can I develop a 3D native software using AVD?

Comment: The answer to your second question is: yes, you need to buy a real android device. Unless your 3D application is utterly trivial, you'll need to playtest on a physical device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in the [official Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html), the Android emulator does not support the OpenGL ES 2.0 features.

[Android x86](http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/) virtual machine also doesn't support OpenGL, but it renders it as 2D graphics, it's not perfect, but it can give 4-5 fps...